# No AbstractFileSystem configured for scheme: gs

Tags: gcloud, gobblin, google-cloud-storage

I am getting below error while running a gobblin job.
My core-site.xml looks fine and it has the required value.

core-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl</name>
  <value>com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS</value>
  <description>The AbstractFileSystem for 'gs:' URIs.</description>
</property>
```

Error

```
org.apache.gobblin.runtime.ForkException: Fork branches [0] failed for task task_toGCPHIVE_1639057335724_14
<Fork 0>
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating writer
    at org.apache.gobblin.writer.PartitionedDataWriter$4.get(PartitionedDataWriter.java:214)
    at org.apache.gobblin.writer.PartitionedDataWriter$4.get(PartitionedDataWriter.java:207)
    at org.apache.gobblin.writer.CloseOnFlushWriterWrapper.<init>(CloseOnFlushWriterWrapper.java:73)
    at org.apache.gobblin.writer.PartitionedDataWriter.<init>(PartitionedDataWriter.java:206)
    at org.apache.gobblin.runtime.fork.Fork.buildWriter(Fork.java:562)
    at org.apache.gobblin.runtime.fork.Fork.buildWriterIfNotPresent(Fork.java:570)
    at org.apache.gobblin.runtime.fork.Fork.processRecord(Fork.java:516)
    at org.apache.gobblin.runtime.fork.AsynchronousFork.processRecord(AsynchronousFork.java:103)
    at org.apache.gobblin.runtime.fork.AsynchronousFork.processRecords(AsynchronousFork.java:86)
    at org.apache.gobblin.runtime.fork.Fork.run(Fork.java:250)
    at org.apache.gobblin.util.executors.MDCPropagatingRunnable.run(MDCPropagatingRunnable.java:39)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:111)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:58)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl=null: No AbstractFileSystem configured for scheme: gs
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.createFileSystem(AbstractFileSystem.java:160)
```

I am able to ran the GS comands in commandline without any issues.
For Ex: `hadoop fs -ls gs://<<bucketName>>` produces the required output.

Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible solutions, if using Scala, pyspark and/or SPARK involve messing with core-site.xml.

The first one is related to How to fix "No FileSystem for scheme: gs" in pyspark?
[No FileSystem for scheme: gs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55595263/how-to-fix-no-filesystem-for-scheme-gs-in-pyspark)

and second one : No Filesystem for Scheme: gs" when running spark job locally
[No Filesystem for Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782844/no-filesystem-for-scheme-gs-when-running-spark-job-locally)

Finally, it could also be an issue with the Cloud Storage connector, I suggest reviewing next document to make sure that your settings were applied correctly.
[Cloud Storage connector](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage) .