# No FileSystem for scheme "gs" Google Storage Connector in plain PySpark installation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-storage

I have already looked at several similar questions - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782844/no-filesystem-for-scheme-gs-when-running-spark-job-locally), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55595263/how-to-fix-no-filesystem-for-scheme-gs-in-pyspark) and some other blog posts and Stack overflow questions.

I have the below PySpark script and looking to read data from a GCS bucket

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .appName("GCSFilesRead")\
    .getOrCreate()

bucket_name="my-gcs-bucket"
path=f"gs://{bucket_name}/path/to/file.csv"

df=spark.read.csv(path, header=True)
print(df.head())
```

which fails with the error -

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o29.csv.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "gs"
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3443)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
```

My environment setup `Dockerfile` is something like below:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.11-jre-slim-buster

# install a whole bunch of apt-get dev essential libraries (unixodbc-dev, libgdbm-dev...)
# some other setup for other services
# copy my repository, requirements file
# install Python-3.9 and activate a venv

RUN pip install pyspark==3.3.1
```

There is no env variable like HADOOP_HOME, SPARK_HOME, PYSPARK_PYTHON etc. Just a plain installation of PySpark.

I have tried to run -

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .appName("GCSFilesRead")\
    .config("spark.jars.package", "/path/to/jar/gcs-connector-hadoop3-2.2.10.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

or

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .appName("GCSFilesRead")\
    .config("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")\
    .config("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")\
    .getOrCreate()
```

and some other solutions, but I am still getting the same error

My question is -

1. **in such a setup, what all do I need to do to get this script running?** I have seen answers on updating pom files, core-site.xml file etc. but looks like simple pyspark installation does not come with those files
2. **how can I make jar installs/setup be a default spark setting in pyspark only installation?** I hope to simply run this script - `python path/to/file.py` without passing any arguments with spark-submit, setting it in the sparksession.config etc.
   I know if we have a regular spark installation, we can add the default jars to spark-defaults.conf file, but looks like plain PySpark installation does not come with those file either

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The error message `No FileSystem for scheme: gs` indicates that Spark does not understand the path to your bucket (gs://) and couldn't find the GCS connector so you will have to mount the bucket first.I suggest reviewing the document to make sure that your settings were applied correctly ,[Cloud Storage connector](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage)
You can also the following:

- Authenticate your user >

`from google.colab import auth auth.authenticate_user()`

- Then install gcsfuse with the following snippet>

`echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt gcsfuse-bionic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list !curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add - !apt -qq update !apt -qq install gcsfuse`

- Then mount the bucket as following>

`mkdir mybucket !gcsfuse mybucket mybucket`
You can store your data then to the following path:
`df.write.csv('/content/my_bucket/df')`

I would also recommend you to have a [look at this thread](https://medium.com/@gsalazarl021990/pyspark-google-colab-to-practice-d699688ac05e) example of a detailed workflow.
You can also try the below once:
To access Google Cloud Storage you have to include Cloud Storage connector:
`spark-submit --jars /path/to/gcs/gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar your-pyspark-script.py`
or
`pyspark --jars /path/to/gcs/gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar`